# bindParam string заключает значение в кавычки, как исключить?

Tags: php, pdo

Пример подготовки:

```
:s idRecord as id, titleBodyRecord as title, dateRecord as date from records where hidden = 0
```

На выходе:

```
'select' idRecord as id, titleBodyRecord as title, dateRecord as date from records where hidden = 0
```

выдает ошибку. (Это всего лишь пример.)

Comment: *как отключить?* В данном конкретном случае - никак. *Это всего лишь пример.* Если пример адекватный - задача не решается. Но в адекватности есть определённые сомнения. Лучше формулируйте настоящую задачу.

Comment: @Akina возможно ли подготовить запрос так, чтобы значение не заключалось в кавычки, это нужно не для постоянного использования. С отключением я загнул, исправил. В голову лезит только конкатенация.

Comment: Ну так собирайте полную строку запроса в переменной, а потом уже скармливайте её PDO. И затем. если нужно, докармливайте её параметрами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Механизм prepared statements может подставлять только значения литералов. Структуру запроса менять нельзя.

У `PDO` при привязке строкового параметра есть две возможности:

- использовать настоящий prepared statements. Тогда никакого экранирования, кавычек - ничего не добавляется, но и значение с текстом запроса никак не взаимодействует, отправляется и обрабатывается на СУБД раздельно. СУБД вам не даст сделать такой `prepare`
- эмулировать prepared statements, подставив корректно экранированное значение строки в текст запроса. Кавычки при этом проставляются всегда, т.к. PDO следует предназначению этого механизма о передачи только параметров запроса, но не структуры. Поэтому для строковых значений кавычки используются всегда.